# How to make the sound move from one channel to the other?

Tags: software, recording, sound

I need to figure out how to make a sound go from the right channel to the left channel (and vice versa) while recording. This effect is typically noticeable when the listener is wearing headphones. An example of this is Pink Floyd's "Don't Leave Me Now" when at the end of the song, Roger Waters shouts and the scream moves from one ear to the other, as if he did it behind the listener's head.
Here's a link: "Don't Leave Me Now" -

Could this be achieved using a software like Pro Tools, Audition, Ableton, Logic, etc. or is it only achievable in a professional recording studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any DAW, Cubase, Pro Tools, Reaper, Sony Acid, Sonar, Fruity Loops or any other, can do it. This is called **panning**.

Naturally the pan is at 0, that is in the center channel or the middle but you can pan from 0 to -100 to the left channel and 0 to 100 to the right channel. Usually to do that you need to use the pan curves or the automation tool or manually pan during recording

And +1 for Pink Floyd, I would even upvote more if I could.

The same effect is in Pink Floyd's song Marooned.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I needed to know what it's called and yeah it's also heard in Marooned (great song!).